# Different conditions (similiar to IF) + uniqe values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i need to filter data using different conditions. One is that I need to queck if the values in one column (column d) are unique IF the values in another column (c) are greater than 1.

Lets assume:
Column a, b, c, d

So I don't want any entries, where c is greater than 1 while d has non unique values.

```
Select TOP 100 * From table
Where (a = 'Max' AND b = '2019') -- just an additional filter, which always applies
    AND (c = 1 -- if c is one, that is fine
            OR (c > 1 AND -- here I want to check if c is bigger than 1 AND if d is unique; but thats the part I need help with
        );
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If `table` has a unique key, use `not exists`, otherwise `count() = 1`, less efficient. Is there a unique key in `table` ?

Comment: And never use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) where you count the distinct values of column `d` and use it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
with cte as (
  select count(distinct d) counter from tablename
)
...........................................
Where ....(c > 1 AND (select counter from cte) = 1)
```

Comment: Would you like to correlate that subquery?

Comment: With a CTE it is certain that it will be executed only once. With the correlates query I'm not sure although I believe the optimizer could do it. Anyway, I thing that CTEs are better for readability and re usability  if needed.

Comment: Your CTE returns a single value: the number of distinct values of `d`. My assumption, in spite of the OP's extensive sample data, was that for each row they wanted to check the combination of `c` and `d` values according to their rules: `c = 1 or ( c > 1 and not exists ( select 42 from NoDDL as ND where ND.NoId <> OuterQuery.NoId and ND.D = OuterQuery.D ) )`. Perhaps the OP might be willing to provide even more sample data and declassify the DDL for the table.

Comment: What I understand from: *I need to queck if the values in one column (column d) are unique* is that the OP needs to check if there is only 1 value in the column d. If this is not the case I guess the OP will clarify.